# How to reverse link foreign key in Django model?

Tags: python, sql, django, model, migration

Here is my model

```
class Comment (models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Comment',
                           related_name='children',
                           null=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.text

class Thread(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment', related_name='parent_thread', null=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.text
```

When I try to set the thread's comment to a comment instance the comment doesn't get reversed linked (I cannot access the related_name field from comment instance)

```
from tree.models import Comment, Thread
thread1 = Thread(text='thread1')
c1 = Comment(text='c1')
c1.save()
thread1.save()
thread1.comment = c1
thread1.save()
str(c1.parent_thread) # return None
```

Why is this happening? Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean c1.parent instead of parent_thread? Django has likely cached the comment before you updated the thread, and therefore you need to re-read it from the database to update the cache.

Comment: thanks, but I meant `c1.parent_thread` , I would like `comment` instance to access `thread` by `parent_thread` using related_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it backwards. If you want to have a `parent_thread`, you have to put the `ForeignKey` into the `Comment` class, not vice versa like this:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    ...

class Comment (models.Model):
    parent_thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    ...
```

In your current code you have *multiple* `Thread` objects linked to a single `Comment` object.

Comment: Your models do not reflect what you say. You cannot traverse a one-to-many relation like that. You can only get all linked threads by `c1.thread_set.all()`.

Comment: so if you need all comments for a thread, then how do you get it?

Comment: thanks, process = models.ForeignKey(HelloWorldProcess, related_name="comments") and something like item.comments.all() works from python code BUT when I do {{ object.comments.all() }} in templates it says Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'object.comments.all()' any extra config is required?, comment_set did not work, so I assume `comment_set` was the `related_name` that was set

Comment: @SrinathGanesh You can't use method arguments in templates, that's why you should omit the parantheses, i.e. just type `{{ object.comment_set.all }}`. `_set` is the default convention to generate a related name unless you override it. If `comments` worked for you go for it :)